# Rails generate error - 'method_missing': undefined method 'active_record'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running Rails 4.2.3 on OS X Yosemite 10.10.4. I currently have two apps that are working fine, however upon creating a new app and trying to use 'rails generate' I am running into the following error message:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007f9d11ae5ed8> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/tompickard/Documents/app/config/application.rb:24:in `<class:Application>'
from /Users/tompickard/Documents/app/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:App>'
from /Users/tompickard/Documents/app/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I have tried various solutions to no avail. 
Please let me know if you need any more information

Thanks

Comment: Is your active_record method defined?

Comment: Where would it be defined?

Comment: Run `gem update --system`

Comment: I am still getting the same error after the update

Comment: rolling back to rails 4.1.0 has fixed it for now